# Swift first selected in collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to get the first selected cell in the collection view. It is showing nil but in the app there is cells showing up. The clientCollectionView is coming up nil too. Here is the function that i am trying to use

```
func currentClient() -> Client? {
    let idx = self.clientsCollectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
    guard let firstSelected = idx?.row else {
        return nil
    }
    return clients()[firstSelected]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return clients().count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "clientCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
    if let cell = cell as? ClientCollectionViewCell {
        cell.client = clients()[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    populateExerciseFields()
}
```

Comment: You need to show more of the enclosing class.  Like the declaration of clientsCollectionView and something to explain when currentClient() is being called.

Comment: i edited it and add the collection view

Comment: What is clientsCollectionView? (please show where you declare it) Why aren't you just using self.collectionView to reference the collection view?

Comment: More context please @MattBrown

Answer (score 0):

```
func currentClient() -> Client? {

// You haven't really explained what "clientsCollectionView" is
// I suspect you just need to replace it with a reference to the
// actual collection view, as shown below. 

let idx = self.collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
guard let firstSelected = idx?.row else {
    return nil
}
return clients()[firstSelected]
}
```

See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller/1623983-collectionview

You are probably referencing some other instance ... but not the one that is associated with your collection view controller.